# Data model in a common web service

Tags: java, web-services, entity, data-modeling, restlet

In a common restful service, there are at least 3 models, they are refer to the same thing, but a little different in different situation.

1. The first model is used to accept data from the post request, with a field `template_id` valued by "id12345".
2. The second model is the DB entity, we also have a DB entity, which also have a `template_id` field, but the type of the field is int, it's a internal template primary key in db, it's a integer.

So I can't directly convert the post data to DB entity to insert to DB.

3. The third model is the rest response, for example, I want to add/remove some field in the model. So I also can't directly convert the DB entity to json response.

So I want to know the good way to process the small differences between these three models.

Do I need to create 3 models named `postDataModel` `DBModel` `responseModel`? I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: The question is interesting :-)

Answer (score 1):

The post data and rest response may be the same, they are both belongs to the Representation layer.

There is a example here. [restlet-tutorial](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial/tree/master/modules/org.restlet.tutorial.webapi)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could read this post about the way to create a Web API (i.e. RESTful service, i.e. a Restlet server application):

- **Designing a Web API**: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/

That said, there are several elements involved when handling a request with Restlet:

- The **application** that receives the request and is responsible to route it to the right handling entity (most commonly a server resource). See the method `Application#createInboundRoot` and the class `Router`.
- The **server resource** that is responsible to handle request. According to the HTTP method used in the request, a method is called within the server resource. See the annotations `@Get`, `@Post`, `@Put`, `@Delete`, ...
- The **request** and the **response** that contain all elements contained in them. Restlet provides an API to get query parameters and headers (see http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/http-headers-mapping).
- The **representation** that corresponds to the data present in request and response payloads.

Whereas you can have access to raw data, Restlet provides a conversion feature that allows you to get these payloads as objects.

You can notice that you can have data types in the payload not only string. In fact, it depends on the structure used for payloads. You can have string values directly or url-encoded forms but also JSON, XML, YAML structures. I guess that you use form so only string values are supported. If it's an issue, feel free to use JSON or something else.

That said, a good approach is to make different representations from DB entities since representations are commonly a bit different. Representations can be subsets or aggregations or several ones. But you can make your life easier by preventing type conversion for attributes. I mean, using same types for attributes in both representations and entities.

Regarding primary keys, there are several ways to handle them:

- They can be **provided by the user** of the RESTful service within representations.
- They can be **generated on the server side** (auto increment, sequence, ...) so it doesn't need to be present within input representations.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry